# elastic search create time based indices

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

According to [Time-Based Data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html), there are mainly two situations to use this kind of method. First it is for logging, es is integrated with Logstash which is default to create a new indices for every day.

However I am in the second condition creating indices for social network activity, and the indices will be created every 3 month automatically, which means the indices name will be **data-01**, **data-04**, **data-07**.

I have search elastic [elastic search reference2.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) and [elastic search : The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) a lot. I have got nothing helpful.

Hopes anyone who can give me a clue or tips.

Comment: Are you populating your ES via Logstash also?

Comment: Not yet, Actually I am employing elastic search as the search engine for Node.js application. Considered index will become very cumbersome as time going. So I just want to find a method to optimise the search, only search for the recent 3 months' data. This is also the reason why I want to create a 3 months interval indices.

Comment: Ok, then how do you currently store our data in ES?

Comment: Also note that you can use date math in the index names while searching: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/date-math-index-names.html to only include the relevant indices in your search

Comment: Combining mongoDB with ES, creating mongoldb  schema first, then creat mapping; All these steps could be found https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic. for the indexing, it will invoke the **index** method which is also provide in the npm package.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Recently I want to know how to create these **time-base indices**, just like **logstash-2024.03.22**, in my situation, it is 3 months interval.

Comment: I'm not certain mongoosastic allows you to change the index name after instantiating the plugin. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear what you mean. it seems no need to change index name, I want to create a new indices with date as part info.

Comment: Yes I understand, though each of those would be a new index, `data-01`, `data-04` and `data-07` are all different indices. We need to find a way to tell mongoosastic to create a new index based on some date. [This issue](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/115) seems to go in that direction but it's still open.

Comment: Maybe I can change the question to make it more common. how could I fulfil these through ES request or setting up. Actually, I don't know how to do this even in the ES request. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks Buddy. As confirmed with my leader. I have made this issue complicated. The resolution is to calculate the date in the source file. Assign a new type name for every 3 months. then ES will create a type if it is not existent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create time-based indices using [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html). Curator lets you create/delete indices, create aliases etc.

So basically you can do the following:

```
1> create an alias which will be used to save data into ES.
2> create a script which will create an index using the current date.
3> detach last months index from the save alias
4> attached the newly created index to your save alias.
5> drop older indices more thatn 30/60/90 days or according to your requirements.
6> write a cron job which will run every month and run this script above.
```

Thus you will have your data saving into a new index every month.

```
7> create another alias for searching with something like indexname* so that it searches across all your existing indices.
```